# Use Bootstrap 5 Form Validation With a Value Length Requirement

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on developing a form and I am currently using Bootstrap 5's CSS validation classes with a custom JS file that toggles the class depending on user entry.  This is working flawlessly.  However, I would like to add a minimum character length requirement that displays the invalid feedback flag until the text contains at least two characters.  Currently, it is showing good even if a single character is entered.  Here are my HTML and JS files.  I am not using any custom CSS at the moment.

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row my-10 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card page-content-card">
                            <form class="page-form needs-validation" action="" method="post" novalidate>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 page-form-section">
                                        <h4 class="page-form-section-text">Personal Info</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-4">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                First name must include at least two characters.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                Last name must include at least two characters.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-floating has-validation">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                Email address must be in format - you@email.com.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 page-form-section">
                                        <h4 class="page-form-section-text">Profile Information</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name" required>
                                            <label for="username">User Name</label>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                User name must contain at least five characters.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                Password must contain at least seven characters.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-floating">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                                            <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row pb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
'use strict'

// Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

// Loop over them and prevent submission
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
    })
```

})()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `minlength` attribute on your inputs.

As stated in the Bootstrap docs:

> All modern browsers support the [constraint validation API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#the-constraint-validation-api), a series of JavaScript methods for validating form controls.
>
> --https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/

If you follow that link you will see a method for `element.validity.tooShort` keep following the links and you find this

> Suffering from being too short
>
> ---
>
> When a control has a value that is too short for the form control minlength attribute (input minlength, textarea minlength).
>
> When the setValidity() method sets tooShort flag to true for a form-associated custom element.
>
> --https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#suffering-from-being-too-short

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row my-10 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card page-content-card">
        <form class="page-form needs-validation" action="" method="post" novalidate>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 page-form-section">
              <h4 class="page-form-section-text">Personal Info</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pb-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required minlength="2">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  First name must include at least two characters.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required minlength="2">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Last name must include at least two characters.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row pb-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const form = document.querySelector('.needs-validation');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      const firstNameInput = document.getElementById('firstname');
      const lastNameInput = document.getElementById('lastname');
      const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
      const passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');

      if (firstNameInput.value.length < 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        firstNameInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
      }

      if (lastNameInput.value.length < 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        lastNameInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
      }

      if (usernameInput.value.length < 5) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        usernameInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
      }

      if (passwordInput.value.length < 7) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        passwordInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
      }
    }

    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row my-10 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card page-content-card">
          <form class="page-form needs-validation" action="" method="post" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 page-form-section">
                <h4 class="page-form-section-text">Personal Info</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pb-4">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pb-3">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-floating has-validation">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Rest of your form content -->
            <div class="row pb-3">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Add Bootstrap JS and custom JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work.  Now I am getting nothing displayed for the invalid message, but still I am getting a green check mark in the box whenever I enter anything in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

juste put pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="..." on your bootstrap input ex :

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).